# Updating UI from a background thread is a bad practice why?

Tags: android, user-interface

My professor told us in the class that updating a UI element from a background task is a bad practice because it might  hang our UI, I can't understand why, can someone please elaborate

Answer (score 2):

Background threads are not aware of your ui state , in simple words they are not aware if your ui still exists or not , in this case if you try to update your ui from the background thread and if by any chance your ui element doen't exist at that time, your app will misbehave (unexpected behaviour) or CRASH .

So to avoid this unexpected behaviour, we only update the ui from the main/ui thread.